# Relate entityId with cygnus auxiliary table

Tags: mysql, fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I'm using persistence with cygnus and MySQL and saving in column type.

How can I relate the entityId field to an auxiliary sensor table?.

Greetings and thank you.